# Removing user from Google Remarketing List

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using Google Adwords Remarketing on my website and it proves to be very effective! However, sometimes I need to remove a user from my remarketing list (after he visits a certain page).

As far as I saw there is no such script that Google provides. However, perhaps there is a workaround of some kinds? Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create the following audiences

A - Your original audience
B - Every one who visits that "certain page"
C - a [combo audience](http://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2549111?hl=en) : (original audience - audience B)

And then only retarget audience C. Anyone who visits your certain page will stop being remarketed to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Elan Perach for an answer that solved the problem for me.  Here is an alternative way which may be preferable, depending on your needs:

You can stop showing a particular remarketing campaign to users who visit "a certain page" by adding a "Campaign audience exclusion" (Campaign > Display Network > Interests & Remarketing > Campaign audience exclusions).

So, referring to Elan's answer, you create audience B ("Everyone who visits that certain page") and add it as an exclusion, but you don't need to create audience C this way. I found this reduced the number of clicks, especially if you want to do this for multiple campaigns.